# Angular js Div show only for 3 seconds

Tags: angularjs

i am new in angular js. i done with div hide and show. just i want to know how to hide or show div for 3 seconds only.
here i attaching my code which i used.

html code:

```
<div ng-hide="loginAlertMessage">Dynamic user feedback message comes here.</div>    
<a ng-click="forgotPassword()">Forgot Password?</a>
```

angular js code:

```
$scope.loginAlertMessage = true;

    $scope.forgotPassword = function () {
         $scope.loginAlertMessage=false;    
    };
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Inject the [`$timeout` service](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$timeout) in the controller and use it to unset `loginAlertMessage`.

```js
app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$timeout', function($scope, $timeout) {
   $scope.loginAlertMessage = true;

   $scope.forgotPassword = function() {
      $scope.loginAlertMessage = false;
      $timeout(function() {
         $scope.loginAlertMessage = true;
      }, 3000);
   };

   // ...
}]);
```

Comment: I am hiding the `ion-nav-bar` when clicked (just for testing). I am doing it this way: `$rootScope.noInternet = true; setTimeout(function() { $rootScope.noInternet = false; }, 3000);` (don't mind the rootscope). It gets hidden, but will never show again.

Comment: @JeroenJK Did you mean to ask a new question?

Comment: No, I didn't, I'm sorry. But I already solved it. I was using `setTimeout` instead of `$timeout`.

Comment: AngularJS: use $timeout, not setTimeout

Answer (score 0):

inject `$timeout` service (derived from `setTimeout(function() {"action",time(in ms) })` in controller and if wish to display make the div true and if wish to hide make use this service to stop.